# comparing the results in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help from members of this group.Im comparing the plans in two tables

Here is an test case

```
create table t11
(
sql_id varchar2(20),
id number,
plan_hash_value number,
OPERATION varchar2(300),
options varchar2(30),
OBJECT_NAME varchar2(30),
cost  number
);

create table t22
(
sql_id varchar2(20),
id number,
plan_hash_value number,
OPERATION varchar2(300),
options varchar2(30),
OBJECT_NAME varchar2(30),
cost  number
);


insert into t11 values('00znbpauyyn1m',0,3587696061,'SELECT STATEMENT',null,null,10);
insert into t11 values('00znbpauyyn1m',1,3587696061,'TABLE ACCESS FULL',null,'TABLE_1',1);
insert into t22 values('00znbpauyyn1m',0,3587696061,'SELECT STATEMENT',null,null,10);
insert into t22 values('00znbpauyyn1m',1,3587696061,'TABLE ACCESS FULL',null,'TABLE_1',1);
insert into t11 values('grfrdz59pu6mc',0,60452177,'SELECT STATEMENT',null,null,5);
insert into t11 values('grfrdz59pu6mc',1,60452177,'INDEX UNIQUE SCAN',null,'TABLE_fry',1);

commit;
```

What i tried

```
select distinct a.sql_id,case when a.Plan_hash_value=b.Plan_hash_value then 'plan same'  when b.Plan_hash_value is null then 'plan not found in table t22' else 'plan changed'   end as status
,(select nvl(to_char(cost),'n/a')  from t11 a  where a.id=0 and a.sql_id=b.sql_id)cost_t11,
(select nvl(to_char(cost),'n/a')  from t22 b where b.id=0 and a.sql_id=b.sql_id)cost_t22
from t11 a left outer join t22 b
on  a.sql_id=b.sql_id;
```

output

```
SQL_ID          STATUS                                 cost_t11  cost_t22
grfrdz59pu6mc   plan not found in table t22     
00znbpauyyn1m   plan same                                 10      10
```

Im comparing the plans in two tables,the above query gives me the required result

Here in the

```
sql_id=grfrdz59pu6mc is only present in table t11 not in t22
```

so  when i use the above query the cost for the `sql_id=grfrdz59pu6mc in table t11 is not displayed.`

I want the cost to be displayed for `t11` table for the `sql_id=grfrdz59pu6mc and n/a(handle null)` in `cost_t22 for sql_id=grfrdz59pu6mc`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `full outer join` and some conditions in the `select` clause:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id,
       (case when a.plan_hash_value is null then 'Plan not found in table t11'
             when b.plan_hash_value is null then 'Plan not found in table t22'
             else 'plans same'
        end) as status,
       a.cost as cost_t11, b.cost as cost_t22
from t11 a full outer join
     t22 b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using teh one proposed by Tom Kyte:

```
  SELECT MAX (tab) tgt,
         rn,
         A,
         B,
         C
    FROM ( (SELECT 'SRC' tab,
                   ROWNUM rn,
                   A,
                   B,
                   C
              FROM TA)
          UNION ALL
          (SELECT 'DST' tab,
                  ROWNUM rn,
                  A,
                  B,
                  C
             FROM TB))
GROUP BY rn,
         A,
         B,
         C
  HAVING COUNT (*) != 2
ORDER BY rn ASC, MAX (tab) DESC
```

works lie a charm :)